# Difficulty to transfer Entity instance from server to client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity

I have an Android client and a Google App Engine Servlet.
And I am transferring objects from client to server by serialization.
Serialization works fine for all the serialized Object in my project,
except to The Entity Object called **Profile** that I am saving in my JPA DB.
now when I am transferring Profile instance from client to server it works fine
but when I transfer from server to client i get the exception as written below.

I'll add that i don't have code duplication in my code.
Profile class is in Server  Project, and Client project contains Server's path.

```
W/System.err(1104): java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity; Incompatible class (SUID): javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity: static final long serialVersionUID =2472141538875317527L; but expected javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity: static final long serialVersionUID =2940818939440220368L;
```

My Enity class is:

```
@Entity
public class Profile implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    private boolean onlineStatus = false;

    public Profile() {}

    public Profile(int age,String email) 
    {
        super();
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() 
    {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) 
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() 
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) 
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isOnlineStatus() 
    {
            return onlineStatus; 
    }

    public void setOnlineStatus(boolean onlineStatus)
    {
        this.onlineStatus = onlineStatus;
    }
```

full stack trace:

```
04-21 21:04:56.577: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2697)
04-21 21:04:56.577: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1825)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:811)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2039)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:916)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1678)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:914)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
04-21 21:04:56.592: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1291)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:518)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1443)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2112)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:916)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1678)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:914)
04-21 21:04:56.597: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1291)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:518)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1443)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2112)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:916)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at streetMeet.Client.CustomHttpClient.readObject(CustomHttpClient.java:274)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at streetMeet.Client.CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(CustomHttpClient.java:59)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at streetMeet.Client.StreetMeetActivity.connectToServer(StreetMeetActivity.java:154)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at streetMeet.Client.StreetMeetActivity.sendMessageToServer(StreetMeetActivity.java:141)
04-21 21:04:56.607: W/System.err(1104): at map.StreetMapActivity$1.run(StreetMapActivity.java:116)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that java object serialization is not guaranteed to work between different VM implementations (GAE JVM and Android Dalvik in this case).

You should use a platform-independent format for serialization. Most popoular is JSON.

Comment: It's also a security issue waiting to happen. Object serialization is not built to cross trust boundaries.